# Intellij flex project mxml: URI is not registered

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, mxml

I'm using latest Intellij to work with flex projects.

in the mxml files i have the following:

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" ...
```

all the urls here are in red and are complaining that "URI is not registered"

any ideas?

Comment: When I worked with a proxy, I had some problems with Intellij. Sometimes when you defined the SDK could hardly have these errors too.

Answer (score 0):

Directly open: Setting - > Project Setting - > Schemas and DTDs,it can be set according to the prompt.

Comment: I believe you can also put the carat over the red url and press alt + enter to be given the option to "register" it.